# Tablet stuck on Checking Connection after Factory Reset

Tags: factory-reset, tablet, connection-issues

Sorry to bother folks, but I'm in a bit of a pickle here! I got this RCA tablet using Android software. It has been running extremely slow as of late, and after removing everything on it, I decided I'd just give it a factory reset and start it back up. The specific model is right here:

"RCA Galileo 11.5" 32 GB Touchscreen Tablet Computer with Keyboard Case Quad-Core 1.3Ghz Processor 1GB Memory 32GB HDD Webcam Wifi Bluetooth Android 8.1 - Blue"
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01MDUH6HX/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MDUH6HX)

Now unfortunately, when it got to the start screen, it said to click language, next.. And then check for connection, after picking one of the available wifi networks. After that? It checks for a long time, and then... Does nothing.

The big issue, is that all the relevant help topics I've seen for this? All deal with PHONES. And most of them all say that you just remove the SIM card. So me, with a tablet here not having a SIM card in it, just a simple lil' dinky thing meant to be like a craptop for work... Am unsure what to do now. And unfortunately, the "Skip" option is greyed out and won't let me click it.

So without an ability to skip forward and just go with base OS and THEN update it afterwards, and no SIM card to pull out for options like that... I am really quite unsure where to go with this! Anyone got any ideas? I'm a bit of a noob obviously when dealing with android, beyond going into the Dev settings and messing with the usual fluff balogna, like turning off animations, vibration-on-touch, only 2-3 active programs at any given time, etc. Can anyone help me with this? I don't need it fancy, I just need this thing running again so I can use it for documentation purposes and viewing PDFs.

TL;DR All help I see is for phones, but this Android Craptop don't work, stuck at "Connecting" and won't let me skip this step. What do Captain Caveman here do?!

Comment: You should be able force a reboot by holding the power button for up to 10 seconds. If the first-time wizard comes again try to skip network set-up (no network no Google account set-up). If the Wifi is still saved shut down your Wifi router for that time.

Comment: there is no option to skip wifi connection dialog on initial setup?

Comment: Again, the issue is that it's not letting me skip. I reset the thing, even hard reset it? Brings me back to the same menu. At the menu, it will NOT let me skip. At all. It stays grey unless I connect to a network, and the only other button is "<" to go back to change language. After that, if I -do- connect... It still won't let me skip the connection test either. Hence where I'm stuck.

Comment: So, does anyone know if I could reimage this thing? It uses "Android 6 Marshmallow" or something. I assume I can use SD Imager to turn a microSD into an image and boot the tablet from there, as I learned how to get into the boot menu, but when I look up Android 6 Marshmallow images, they all say they're for Nexus or something? And there's like, 30 versions? Again, I don't need this thing 'factory mint', I just need it workable and able to open up PDFs and word documents and MAYBE other apps. Anyone know if using one of these images would work?

Comment: I don't have a solution to this, but I found in some other pages on this forum advice to use ADB while in a custom recovery mode to simply disable the Setup Wizard itself; unfortuantely, this doesn't work at all. Does anyone have a solution to this?